# How to transfer value from chrome.storage when changed in popup.js to content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to transfer value from popup.js to content.js.

Overall, it works. But I can't do "live" change, because content.js loads old value of chrome.storage.

**popup.js**

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ 
      text: form.textContent, // form.textContent = "1"
    });
});

chrome.storage.sync.get(["text"]).then((result) => {
      pageText.textContent = result.text; // result.text = "2"
    });
```

**content.js**

```
function getInterval() { //test
    chrome.storage.sync.get(["text"]).then((result) => {
      pageText.textContent = result.text; //result.text = "1"
    });
}
```

Initially result.text (storage) is "1", saved from previous time;
I change value in popup to "2".
If I try to read it via sync.get in popup.js I get it as "2"
But when I try to read it from content.js its "1"

But if I refresh tab, result.text = 2 in content.js.

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Hi, if you want to see "live" the new value you have also to transmit it to content script via chrome.runtime.sendMessage. On the other side you'll have to listen that message with chrome.runtime.onMessage

Comment: Or use chrome.storage.onChanged event in the content script.